# Cloudflare + Heroku = Free SSL - Not working properly

Tags: node.js, ssl, heroku, cloudflare

So i tried this: [Heroku + Cloudflare completely free SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131611/heroku-cloudflare-completely-free-ssl)
It worked at the beginning smoothly but now i get this warning: "Server's certificate does not match the URL"
I get it from every browser! The icon i get: http://grab.by/AYGu

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because I don't have a cloudflare certificate anymore (even though it says I have in the cloudflare settings).