# Rails Heroku Cloudflare SSL and websockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, websocket, cloudflare, websocket-rails

I have set up my Rails app on Heroku and used the information in the post: [Heroku + Cloudflare completely free SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131611/heroku-cloudflare-completely-free-ssl) to get SSL working for free, but my websockets connection does not work. I get the error `WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.myapp.com/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200`. I understand that this is due to Cloudflare not supporting websockets in their free plans and they suggest setting up a subdomain that does not pass through Cloudflare. The problem of course is that the subdomain cannot then use the 'free' SSL setup.

Is there anyway I can get this to work, or do I have to shell out for either SSL support on Heroku or Websocket support on Cloudflare?

Comment: Just hit this problem myself -.-

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread.

But now cloudflare supports websocket for free plan as well. It just restricts the ports which can be used.

I recently encountered this situation and could implement the **websockets through cloudflare**.
Can refer my approach [here](https://github.com/AmitTeli/cloudflare-websocket)

May help someone.